# Calculate Result Sum

Tags: powershell, sum

When I run the code below as not aggregated then I’m getting a correct result as below.

```
$StartDate = Get-Date "2/14/2019";
$EndDate = $StartDate.AddDays(1);
[string] $email = xxxx@xxx.com;

$ExchServers = Get-ExchangeServer | where {
    $_.isHubTransportServer -eq $true -or
    $_.isMailboxServer -eq $true
} | Select-Object Name
$Servers = $ExchServers.Name 
foreach ($server in $Servers) {
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server $server -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate -ResultSize unlimited -Eventid “receive” -Source "storedriver" -Sender $email |
        Group-Object -Property Sender |
        Select-Object Count |
        sort Count -Desc |
        ft -Auto
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server $server -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate -ResultSize unlimited -Eventid “deliver” -Source "storedriver" -Recipients $email |
        Group-Object -Property Sender |
        Select-Object Count |
        sort Count -Desc |
        ft -Auto
}
```

```
Count
------
4

Count
------
2
2
1
1
1
1
```

That is Sent: 4; Received: 8

But, when I try to aggregate it with `| ForEach { $totalRsvd++ }`

```
$StartDate = Get-Date "2/14/2019"
$StartDate
$EndDate = $StartDate.AddDays(1)
[string] $email = xxxx@xxx.com;

$totalSent = 0;
$totalRsvd = 0;
$ExchServers = Get-ExchangeServer | where {
    $_.isHubTransportServer -eq $true -or
    $_.isMailboxServer -eq $true
} | Select-Object Name
$Servers = $ExchServers.Name 
foreach ($server in $Servers){
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server $server -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate -ResultSize unlimited -Eventid “receive” -Source "storedriver" -Sender $email |
        Group-Object -Property Sender |
        Select-Object Count | sort Count -Desc |
        ft -Auto |
        ForEach { $totalSent++ } 
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server $server -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate -ResultSize unlimited -Eventid “deliver” -Source "storedriver" -Recipients $email |
        Group-Object -Property Sender |
        Select-Object Count |
        sort Count -Desc |
        ft -Auto |
        ForEach { $totalRsvd++ }
}
Write-Host "Email Qty sent: ", $totalSent; 
Write-Host "Email Qty Received: ", $totalRsvd
```

```
Email Qty sent:  5
Email Qty Received:  10
```

The result is incorrect.

Comment: you are trying to use the output of FT [`Format-Table`] for something other than final display or final to-text-file use. DO NOT DO THAT!. [*grin*] why? because the `Format-Table` & `Format-List` cmdlet _destroy_ your objects - you only get the butchered remnants wrapped in formatting code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I took off  "| ft -auto " but I'm getting the incorrect result anyway as Sent: 1 and Received: 6 comparing with the correct one that should be 4 and 8.

Comment: why are you using `$totalRsvd++` or `$totalSent++` at that point? the code looks like it will hold an object with one property named `.Count` with an integer value in it. your `$totalRsvd++` simply adds one to the value in `$totalRsvd` - it does NOT appear to be looking at the value in the `.Count` property. ///// i can't test your code since i have no such systems available, but i suspect you could use `$TotalRcvd += $_.Count` to add the value in that prop to the accumulator $var.

Comment: Great! It's working. Thanks a lot

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]